# If cell is true take value from another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Column A contains some numbers, while column B contains `TRUE` and `FALSE` values.

```
A     B
-     -
1     TRUE
2     FALSE
3     FALSE
4     TRUE
5     TRUE
```

In column C, for every `TRUE` value in column B, take the value in column A in order not the row the `TRUE` value in in.

For example:

```
C
-
1
FALSE
FALSE
2
3
```

When I try to do something like this, all the `TRUE` values take the number in column A in the row the `TRUE` value is in.

For example:

```
C
-
1
FALSE
FALSE
4
5
```

So, when the desired result is 2 and 3 in the last two `TRUE` values, the `IF` formula takes the value from column A in the row the `TRUE` value is in, which in this case is 4 and 5.

Is there any method to take the value in order if the value in column B is `TRUE`?

Comment: So column A does in fact not have any influence on column C? Because given your example, Column C is just the count of TRUE values so far. Or what happens, if column A for instance has values 1,3,5,7,9,11,13  instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7?

Comment: @derpirscher Column A should have an influence on column C as, for example, the third `TRUE` value will take the third value in column A as oppose to the row the third `TRUE` value is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula seems to do the trick.

This is my testsheet:

[image]

In C2 I have this formula:

```
=IF(B2="True",1,"False")
```

In C3 (and drag down):

```
=IF(B3="True",1+MAX($C$2:C2),"False")
```

Comment: Excel is returning an error when trying to enter the formula.

Comment: Sorry my local settings is to have `;` as delimiter in formulas, but the English way is `,`

Comment: Yes, your solution does work correctly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Be aware, that this only works, if the values in column A are like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. But for such a situation, you can also use `=if(b2="true"; countif($b$2:b2;"true"); "false")` Also be aware, that with this solution, the values in column A don't have any influence on the values in column C (which you explicitely requested in your question)

Comment: Something to consider in `C2` > `=IF(B2,SUMPRODUCT(--B$2:B2))`

Comment: @JvdV Your solution is more compact, however, seems to only work for when values are sequenced.

Answer (score 0):

You need another assisting column, let's say D

D should work like this:

- if B = true then take A value
- if B = false then take previous D value (1 row up)

and then you'd be able to use D for your C - take D value instead of A.